# Codeigniter query issue

Tags: codeigniter, model

I am running the following query in codeiginter, I want to return the data from the database but I'm getting a blank array as a response. My attempts to debug this issue have shown that the return value from the model may be the issue. I need a extra pair of eyes on this so if anyone can help me let me know.

Model

```
function test($term)
{

    $sql = "select description from category where title = '$term'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller

```
    function test()
{
    $this->load->model('test');
    $term = $this->input->post('term',TRUE);
    $rows = $this->test->test($term);
    echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

Comment: just echo the query and run it in your mysql editor to know whether it returns any data

Comment: echo $term , var_dump $rows , what are the results , please try something berfore posting a question

Comment: Can you include a php variable in a string like that? Should it not be : `"select description from category where title = '".$term."'";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks correct... try printing the last query that was made and check it out

**COntroller**

```
function test()
{
  $this->load->model('test');
  $term = $this->input->post('term',TRUE);
  $rows = $this->test->test($term);
  echo $this->db->last_query();exit; //this gives you the last query that was made.
  echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

check if the posted value is correct... you can even try running this in mysql and see if this is returning any rows...

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have run many test to see where the issue was and your suggestion help he found the problem. The issue was that a leading whitespace was added to $term that was causing the blank array to be display. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

use `echo $this->db->last_query();` and get you query and try it with your mysql editor

Answer (score 0):

I notice by running echo $this->db->last_query(); the value of $term had a leading white space that cause the query to return null. by adding $term = trim($term, " "); I was able to remove the leading white space and get the correct result.

```
 $this->load->model('tp_model');
 $term = $this->input->post('term',TRUE);
$term = trim($term, " ");
$rows = $this->tp_model->test($term);
```